# All max value in dataframe with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': ["x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y"],'C3': [12,  12,   7,   3,   6,   9]})
print (df)
```

and the output is:

```
  C1  C3
0  x  12
1  x  12
2  x   7
3  y   3
4  y   6
5  y   9
```

When I tried to get the max value of each item of `C1` in `C3` I used:

```
df1 = df.groupby('C1').agg(max_ = ('C3', lambda data: data.idxmax()))
print (df1)
```

and the output is:

```
C1  max_    
x      0
y      5
```

**But I want that the output be:**

```
C1  max_    
x      0
x      1
y      5
```

because `x` has two max values (12).

Where is the error? I need find all max values, not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's `groupby` on `C1` and `transform` the column `C3` using `max` then compare this transformed column with `C3` to create a boolean mask `m`, then filter the rows in `df` using this mask and `drop` the column `C3` and `assign` the column `_max`:

```
m = df['C3'] == df.groupby('C1')['C3'].transform('max')
df1 = df[m].drop('C3', 1).assign(_max=m[m].index)
```

---

```
print(df1)
  C1  _max
0  x     0
1  x     1
5  y     5
```